# Allingment issue in html - need to get the record in right corner

Tags: html, alignment

I have added a new row .

for defaultGPnamer i need to bring that to the right end.

Please help on this .

attached the code

```html
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</LayoutTemplate>        
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div  class="rounded" style="margin-left:10px">
                    <table style="width: 560px; height:95px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="height:22px">
                            <div>
                                <span style="font-size:11pt; color:#008FBE; font-weight:bold; line-height: 22px"><%#Eval("MMHMember")%><%#Eval("UserName") %></span>&nbsp;
                                <i><b><%#Eval("gender")%> <%#Eval("Age","{0} Yrs</b>") %></b></i>&nbsp;
                                <span><%#Eval("DateOfBirth")%>
                                </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right">
                            <span style="color:#008FBE; font-size:11pt; line-height: 22px;"><%#Eval("NHINumber")%></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbldefaultgp" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold;color:#008FBE;"><%#Eval("DefaultGPName")%></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top">
                            <td style="width:100px;">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgPatientPhoto" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#GetPhotoURL(Eval("PhotoURL","{0}"))%>' style="width:90px;height:95px" />
                            </td>
                            <td  style="width: 125px">
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblHome" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("HomePhone")%></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblWork" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("WorkPhone")%></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMobail" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("Mobilenumber")%></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:140px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("Address") %></asp:Label>
                            </td>           
                            <td style="" >
                                <asp:Label runat ="server" ID ="lblEnrolledPractice"><%#Eval("businessname") %> </asp:Label>   <br />
                                <asp:Label runat ="server" ID ="lblCasualPractice"><%#Eval("CasualBusinessname") %> </asp:Label>                   
                                <p>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewConsentSetting" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="ConsentSetting" Visible="<%# ApplyCareSetting %>" >View Consent Settings</asp:LinkButton>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewHealthSummary" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="HealthSummary" Visible ='<%# SetHESVisible("SEHR") %>'>View Health Summary</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewHealthSummaryConsent" runat="server" Visible ='<%# SetHESVisible("CONSENT") %>' Text="View Health Summary"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

I would be greatful if someone can help on this.

Label id is lbldefaultgp.

need to bring that data to right end in the banner.

notes::::

Answer (score 0):

```html
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</LayoutTemplate>        
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div  class="rounded" style="margin-left:10px">
                    <table style="width: 560px; height:95px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="height:22px">
                            <div>
                                <span style="font-size:11pt; color:#008FBE; font-weight:bold; line-height: 22px"><%#Eval("MMHMember")%><%#Eval("UserName") %></span>&nbsp;
                                <i><b><%#Eval("gender")%> <%#Eval("Age","{0} Yrs</b>") %></b></i>&nbsp;
                                <span><%#Eval("DateOfBirth")%>
                                </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right">
                            <span style="color:#008FBE; font-size:11pt; line-height: 22px;"><%#Eval("NHINumber")%></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
     
     
     
     <tr>
     <td colspan="3" style="height:22px">
                            <div>
                                 
                            </div>
                        </td>
     
       <td>
                           <p>is this the thing you want?</p> <asp:Label ID="lbldefaultgp" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold;color:#008FBE;"><%#Eval("DefaultGPName")%></asp:Label>
                        </td>
     
     </tr>
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
                    
                      
                    
                        <tr style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top">
                            <td style="width:100px;">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgPatientPhoto" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#GetPhotoURL(Eval("PhotoURL","{0}"))%>' style="width:90px;height:95px" />
                            </td>
                            <td  style="width: 125px">
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblHome" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("HomePhone")%></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblWork" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("WorkPhone")%></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMobail" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("Mobilenumber")%></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:140px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"><%#Eval("Address") %></asp:Label>
                            </td>           
                            <td style="" >
                                <asp:Label runat ="server" ID ="lblEnrolledPractice"><%#Eval("businessname") %> </asp:Label>   <br />
                                <asp:Label runat ="server" ID ="lblCasualPractice"><%#Eval("CasualBusinessname") %> </asp:Label>                   
                                <p>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewConsentSetting" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="ConsentSetting" Visible="<%# ApplyCareSetting %>" >View Consent Settings</asp:LinkButton>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewHealthSummary" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="HealthSummary" Visible ='<%# SetHESVisible("SEHR") %>'>View Health Summary</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewHealthSummaryConsent" runat="server" Visible ='<%# SetHESVisible("CONSENT") %>' Text="View Health Summary"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
```